# Prove that $f_n(z)= \prod_{k|n} (z^k-1)^{\mu(n/k)}$

Tags: combinatorics, mobius-function

I have the following problem and I would really like some hint or suggestion on where to start working since I have no idea.

The problem is as follows: Let $f_n(z)$ be the function that has as its zeros all numbers $\eta$ for which $\eta^n=1$ but $\eta^k \neq 1$ for $1 \leq k <n$. Prove that $f_n(z)= \prod_{k|n} (z^k-1)^{\mu(n/k)}$.

Thanks for the help and suggestions!

Comment: I can't edit but could you add a '$' to the end of 'mu(n/k)}' so MathJax can process it?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just corrected it.

Comment: that's the exclusion/inclusion principle from which you get the Möbius invertion formula (note that you forgot to say $f_n(z)$ as only simple zeros)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I suggested you to pay attention to the hypothesis, 
because there are infinitely many functions $f_{n}(z)$ with your properties;

I think that you ask about a polynomial one, i.e about $f_{n}(z)=\phi_{n}(z)=\displaystyle \prod_{\zeta}(z-\zeta)$,the $n-th$ cyclotomic polynomials, with $\zeta$ that goes over all the primitive $n-th$ root of unity, i.e. the number that satisfies $\zeta^{n}=1,\zeta^{k}\neq 1,\forall 1\leq k<n$.

In this case is quite easy to find that $z^{n}-1=\displaystyle \prod_{k|n}\phi_{k}(z)$ because $z^{n}-1=\displaystyle \prod_{k|n}\prod_{\zeta^{k}=1}(z-\zeta)$, since $z^{n}-1$ have as root all the $n-th$ root of unity and a generic $n-th$ root of unity $\zeta$ satisfy $\zeta^{k}=1$ for some $k|n$ (essentially for Lagrange theorem applied to the group of all the $n-th$ root of unity).

Now you can procede by apply the Mobius inversion formula (for the product) to this equality and to find that $\phi_{n}(z)=\displaystyle \prod_{k|n}(z^{k}-1)^{\mu(\frac{n}{k})}$.

Comment: 'a polynomial one' : a polynomial with only simple roots